# Excel VBA - apply data validation to created worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have VBA code that creates an xlsx file.
I need to apply data validation to a range of that file.
Recording a macro, I got this code:

```
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateDecimal, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
        :=xlBetween, Formula1:="-30", Formula2:="-0,25"
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = "ATTENTION"
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = "Numbers must be between -0.25 and -30.00"
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I edited the above code to my needs:

```
With students.Range(MyNegRangePoints).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateDecimal, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
    :=xlBetween, Formula1:="-30", Formula2:="-0,25"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "ATTENTION!"
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = "The points must be negative!"
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

MyNegPointsRange is "B2:D2" but could change.

When I run the code I get run-time error 1004 (error defined by application or object) here:

```
        .Add Type:=xlValidateDecimal, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
        :=xlBetween, Formula1:="-30", Formula2:="-0,25"
```

I think it's related to the double quotes, but I've tried several combinations with no luck.

Note that this preceding code works well:

```
    With students.Range(MyPosRange).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
             xlBetween, Formula1:="=OR(" & FirstCellPos & " ="""", " & FirstCellPos & " =""X"")"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = "ATTENTION!"
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = "Just enter X to select this cell"
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: It's definitely not related to the quotes (tested). You mentioned a `.xlsx` file, then you used a worksheet with the code name `students` meaning that you are in `ThisWorkbook`, the workbook containing this code which has to be `.xlsm` or `.xlsb` when saved, so you're not doing it to another workbook with a `.xlsx` extension. Please do clarify in which workbook and worksheet the data validation has to be created. Maybe adding the preceding code could help.

Comment: ... the short version is that only the first line is wrong, or more accurately, the `students.Range(MyNegRangePoints)` part.

Comment: I debugged the code in VBA Editor but MyNegRangePoints correctly is "B2:D2". I don't understand what's wrong...

Comment: I solved the issue! I must write -0.25 instead of -0,25 but strangely in other parts of my code I use "," in decimal numbers and it works!
(I use Italian Excel and in Italy we use "," in decimal numbers")